# MAMP is working correctly, but URL is bringing up a blank page

Tags: wordpress, mamp

I was working on my wordpress site locally using MAMP and suddenly everything went blank (white).  Apache and MySQL both have green lights and everything seems to be running just fine, but the URL brings up a blank page now with no error message.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the Apache logs? I bet there's something that prevents the page from loading. Also, have you tried other URLs on the same server?

Comment: Your server might compress HTTP 500 errors? As miq mentions - check your logs, or look clientside for what HTTP respond-code you get.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  I have checked my apache log and this is what it reads:
authentication ...
[Fri May 09 12:48:36 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 09 12:48:36 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/5.5.10 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations.

I'm still a bit of a novice on this heavy back end stuff so i really appreciate the help.  I'm not 100% sure what this error means but I would appreciate any insight.  I haven't tried any other urls cuz I have just one site on it.

Comment: Here's another error :[Fri May 09 12:52:38 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri May 09 12:52:45 2014] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 5089)
[Fri May 09 12:52:46 2014] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri May 09 12:52:46 2014] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri May 09 12:52:46 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/5.5.10 mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/0.9.8y DAV/2 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.18.2 configured -- resuming normal operations

Comment: I fixed it, and I'm kicking myself.  Turns out it wasn't any type of server or database issue.  I had made an edit in my functions.php file in wordpress that created an error, and that must have been what was being picked up and causing the issues.  However, my error log wasn't giving me the php error until I re-installed MAMP and created a new database.  Once I fixed the error, everything worked right as rain.  Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The white screen usually happens when you edit something in the php and it is incorrect formatting.  Go back through the edits and changes you recently made to the code and remove the changes.  You should then see your site and know which pieces of code are throwing the errors.  It happened to me a few times.

Comment: Yep, that's what it was, a faulty edit in my functions.php file.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  Go ahead and mark this resolved by clicking the checkbox next to my answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to attempting to connect to the wrong database as my wp-config.php had a typo in it. I found the solution by first looking at apache logs as mentioned and there was only a general SIGTERM error. I  then looked at MAMP's php_error.log which showed me this error: `WordPress database error Unknown column 'wp_' in 'field list' for query SELECT wp_`. Updating my wp-config with the correct database and restarting MAMP fixed the issue.